# tracking beat and detecting onsets musical analys

Tags: python, audio, artificial-intelligence, librosa

I'm doing a project of a musical fountain. I started with the simulation, so i use Librosa to extract informations from music. I want to use the following parameters :
1- Onset Detection
2- Beat Tracking

I can create code that use one of them, so i started with detecting onsets. But sometimes it is not enough to use only the onset data, and that.s why i wanna add beat tracking. How can i do?

Here is my code :

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, animation
import pygame
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# Initialiser pygame
pygame.mixer.init()

# Charger le fichier audio
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
audio_path = askopenfilename()
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_path)

# Charger la chanson avec pygame
pygame.mixer.music.load(audio_path)




# Détecter les onsets dans la chanson
onset_frames = librosa.onset.onset_detect(y=y, sr=sr)

# Nombre d'onsets dans la chanson
n_onsets = len(onset_frames)

# Calcul du chromagramme
chroma = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=y, sr=sr, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512)

# Sélection des temps pertinents
temps = librosa.frames_to_time(onset_frames, sr=sr, hop_length=512)

# Sélection des colonnes du chromagramme correspondant aux temps pertinents
chroma = chroma[:, onset_frames]

# Normalisation du chromagramme
chromanorm = librosa.util.normalize(chroma, norm=2, axis=0)

# Initialiser la liste de hauteurs avec les valeurs du chromagramme
hauteurs = [[] for _ in range(n_onsets)]
for i in range(n_onsets):
    for j in range(12):
        hauteur = chromanorm[j, i]
        hauteurs[i].append(hauteur)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlim(0, 13)

bar_collection = ax.bar(range(1, 13), [0]*12, align='center', linewidth=0.5)

# La durée d'une frame en millisecondes est égale à la moyenne des intervalles de temps entre chaque onset multipliée par 1000 pour avoir des millisecondes
frame_duration = np.mean(np.diff(temps))*1000

def animate(i):
    for j, b in enumerate(bar_collection):
        b.set_height(hauteurs[i][j])
    return bar_collection

# Fonction pour lancer la chanson avec pygame
def play_music():
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
play_music()

# Définir les paramètres de l'animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=n_onsets, interval=frame_duration, blit=True)

anim.repeat = False
plt.show()
```

Tried to use beat tracking alone, detecting onsets alone, but cant simulate both of them

Comment: What does it mean "Tried to use beat tracking alone, detecting onsets alone, but cant simulate both of them"? What exactly are you stuck with